# Add scrollbar to mentions list in react-mentions

Tags: reactjs

I am using react mentions in my application. I am having more items in suggesstions list. Is it possible to fix a height and add scrollbar to it?

https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add style like this.

```
.mentions__suggestions__list {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or provide inline styling in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution only by CSS in my case; I put it in a card and assigned an id example: id "mentionable" and by CSS I applied an `overflow: auto;`

```
    #chartDashboard > div > div > div > div >  div > svg > g > g >
 circle { fill: #DEDC00;}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggdZe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmrWI.png)